# Perform persistant background operation with phonegap app

Tags: cordova, service

I want to build a mobile app and heard of the PhoneGap framework,
and I need to perform operations on the background even when my application is not running (like a service).

I would like to know if it's possible with PhoneGap, or even if I can attach a service built natively to my PhoneGap app.

Thank you.

Comment: Not really duplicates, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343828/creating-an-android-service-with-phonegap-have-phonegap-app-run-even-when-clos and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191139/phonegap-background-service-in-ios5. tl;dr, not possible. It will probably be simplest to go native or rework to be a web service with push notifications.

Comment: So if I need an app which needs a service,
Would PhoneGap be the right choice for developing the app,
and native language to develop the service?

Is it possible to make them both like one-package?

Comment: Yes, I think it is possible, but I don't know any more than that.

Comment: you can create phonegap plugin to work as a service. creating plugins is quite simple.