# Schedule task to run at a certain time in phonegap ios?

Tags: ios, html, cordova, objective-c-blocks, phonegap-plugins

Good afternoon,
in the application I'm doing, I have some data in my table every day at a certain time are going to be sent to the server,
the hourly will be determined by the User.
The data has to be sent regardless of the application is running or not.
I'm looking for some way to trigger this task. Android seems to have a plugin for it but IOS has nothing like that.
Anyone know how to do this
from already thank you

att,
Julio

Answer (score 1):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191139/phonegap-background-service-in-ios5) question is very similar to the task you want to accomplish.
Based on some event, you want to trigger a task to send data to the server.
I'm not an expert in the iOS world, but the suggestion in this case was: "The reasonable solution would be to implement a push notification and send a notification whenever there is an update on server.".

If this is something you think reasonable, too, consider to use the [GenericPush](http://phonegap.com/blog/build/introducing-genericpush-plugin/) plugin.
I've already implemented an app in the Android world and it works very well, no experience in the iOS world yet.